# I want to use url parameters as optional filters django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a django rest framework application and I want to use my url parameters as optional filtering for queryset it they are given in the url.

Right now, i am trying to grab the parameters from the url and they are not grabbing, it is also then not applying the parameters as a filter.

can someone help me wit this.

urls:

```
router.register(r'preferences', PreferenceUserViewSet, basename='Preference')
router.register(r'preferences/(?P<namespace>\w+)', PreferenceUserViewSet, basename='Preference-namespace')
router.register(r'preferences/(?P<namespace>\w+)/(?P<path>\w+)', PreferenceUserViewSet, basename='Preference-path')
```

viewset:

```
class PreferenceUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    model = Preference
    serializer_class = PreferenceSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == 'create' or self.action == 'destroy':
            permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
        else: 
            permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
        return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]
    @permission_classes((IsAuthenticated))
    def get_queryset(self):
        namespace = self.request.query_params.get('namespace', None)
        path = self.request.query_params.get('path', None)
        print(namespace)
        print(path)
        queryset = Preference.objects.filter(user_id=1)
        if path is not None:
            queryset = Preference.objects.filter(user_id=1, namespace=namespace)
        if namespace is not None:
            queryset = Preference.objects.filter(user_id=1, namespace=namespace, path=path)
        return queryset
```

So i want to either just filter based off user_id if there is no namespace or path passed in. I want to filter based off user_id and namespace if namepsace is passed in and path is not passed in. I want to filter based off user_id and namespace and path if all three values are passed in. I looked at all the docs but I couldnt figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `self.request.query_params`, you should use `self.kwargs` in your `get_queryset` method, since `namespace` and `path` are not *query parameters* but *arguments* of the URL.

```
class PreferenceUserViewSet(...):
    ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        namespace = self.kwargs.get('namespace', None)
        path = self.kwargs.get('path', None)

        ...
```