# how to get a string parametr in drf modelviewset

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

i need to use a path with an optional paramentr, to specify a user via a srting a request would look like 'api/users/specific_username' or 'api/users' for all users

urls:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', MyUserViewSet, basename='user-me')
```

views:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        if self.kwargs['username']:
            username=self.request.GET.get('username')
            queryset = User.objects.filter(username=username)
        return queryset
```

`username=self.kwargs['username']`
returns KeyError
`username=self.request.GET.get('username')`
returns None

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56939521/i-want-to-use-url-parameters-as-optional-filters-django-rest-framework you need to add `username` to url path in register

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to achieve that by doing like so:
so for request that looks like so:

```
http://example.com/api/viewset?username=denvercoder9
```

the code will look this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    """
    Optionally restricts the returned purchases to a given user,
    by filtering against a `username` query parameter in the URL.
    """
    queryset = Purchase.objects.all()
    username = self.request.query_params.get('username', None)
    if username is not None:
        queryset = queryset.filter(purchaser__username=username)
    return queryset
```

or if you really want you override the retrieve:
*(haven't tested this code)*

```
def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
    queryset = User.objects.filter(username=pk)
    contact = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=1)
    serializer = ContactSerializer(contact)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```